# "Ambiguous use of 'propertyName'" error given overridden property with didSet observer

Tags: swift

I've got a simple scenario in which I have a parent class, Person, which defines a property called "name" and includes a "didSet" observer...

```
class Person {

    var name: String? {
    didSet {
        println("Person name was set.")
    }
    }

    init() {}
}
```

I also have a subclass of Person called Employee which adds its own "didSet" observer for the "name" property so that it can monitor changes to that property...

```
class Employee: Person {

    override var name: String? {
    didSet {
        println("Employee name was set.")
    }
    }

}
```

When I try to exercise the code I get compile error but I can't figure out why or how to fix it. Here's the code that exercises these classes...

```
var person = Person()
person.name = "Bob"

var employee = Employee()
employee.name = "Sally"  // results in "Ambiguous use of 'name'" compile error
```

Comment: I am able to run this code without error. Even after adding `println(employer.name)` I get "Sally" outputted.

Comment: Same, are you sure nothing else is interfering with your code?

Comment: I'm not sure what else might be interfering. That "exercise" code I list is in the application(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) method in my AppDelegate class.

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that you're not alone in having issues with overriding. I've got the same problem whilst trying to essentially replicate code from the Swift Programming Language.

Comment: As a follow-up, this is a known bug: https://twitter.com/jckarter/status/475664088412856320

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As @sgaw points out, this has been confirmed as a known bug by the Apple engineers (for Xcode 6 Beta - Version 6.0 (6A215l))

https://devforums.apple.com/thread/229668?tstart=0

Comment: Anybody know how to work around this bug until Apple fixes it?  I'm seeing the exact same behavior for a situation that I would consider particularly unambiguous :P

Comment: @user1021430: I just ran into the problem. I have a method returning [UIColor]. With let colors = method() - explicit casting got rid of the error - let colors = method() as [UIColor]. My assumption was that ambiguity points to the compiler not knowing what to make of the return value.

Comment: But the issue persists

Comment: I'm seeing this with static extensions on types. I'm unable to say ProjectName.TypeName since the type is internal.

Answer (score 22):

I was able to work around this in my case by casting to the base class:

```
(employee as Person).name = "Sally"
```

This still appears to do the proper dispatch to the subclass. For instance:

```
class Person {
    var name: String {
            return "person"
    }
}

class Employee: Person {
    override var name: String {
        return "employee"
    }
}

let bob = Person()
let alice = Employee()

println((alice as Person).name) // prints "employee"
```

Answer (score 7):

I got this error because I had two properties declared with the same name.

On Objective-C the compiler used to give the error on the line the property was declared. Something like "duplicate property".

Now on Swift you get "Ambiguous use of..." on the line that you use to property... and you have to look everywhere to find the duplicate property.