# What is the right way to override a property in a subclass in Swift?

Tags: ios, inheritance, properties, swift, overriding

I also stumbled upon this question, however, there is no definitive answer

> ["Ambiguous use of 'propertyName'" error given overridden property with didSet observer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087011/ambiguous-use-of-propertyname-error-given-overridden-property-with-didset-ob)

**Problem:** I would like to override a property in a subclass.

Let me illustrate the problem with an example:

I have a class called `A` and a subclass thereof called `B`.

#### Class A

```
class A {

    var someStoredProperty : Int? 

}
```

#### Class B

```
class B : A{

    override var someStoredProperty : Int?{

        willSet{

            //add to superclass's setter 
            someStoredProperty = newValue! + 10
        }

    }

}
```

As soon as I try to set the inherited property of `B`

```
var b = B()
b.someStoredValue = 10 // Ambiguous use of someStoredProperty
```

the compiler tells me

`Ambiguous use of someStoredProperty`

Why is that ?

### Update

```
class TableViewRow{

    typealias ClickAction = (tableView:UITableView, indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> Void
    var clickAction : ClickAction?
}

class SwitchTableViewRow: TableViewRow {

    override var clickAction : ClickAction? {

        didSet{

            //override setter
        }

    }

}
```

Usage:

```
var switchRow = SwitchTableViewRow()
switchRow.clickAction = {    
       //^
       //|
       //|
 //ambiguous use of clickAction
[unowned self, unowned switchRow] (tableView: UITableView, indexPath: NSIndexPath) in

    //do something

}
```

Comment: you should check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087011/ambiguous-use-of-propertyname-error-given-overridden-property-with-didset-ob

Comment: @tudoricc That is exactly the link I posted in the question.......

Comment: Sorry for reposting that question but when I first looked I saw `some-text` and not a link.sorry once again

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't get that error in 6.1, but the underlying problem is you have an infinite loop here. What you meant to say is:

```
// This is wrong, but what you meant
override var someStoredProperty: Int? {
    willSet {
        super.someStoredProperty = newValue! + 10
    }
}
```

Note the `super`. (Which is yet another reason I strongly recommend using `self.` on properties, to make it clear when these infinite loops exist.)

But this code is meaningless. Before setter, you set the value to `x + 10`. You then set the value to `x`. What you really meant was:

```
override var someStoredProperty: Int? {
    didSet {
        if let value = someStoredProperty {
            super.someStoredProperty = value + 10
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While I agree with your point, the real problem is not the resulting value, but the compilation error. I think I came across this error before, but I have no idea what is causing it...

Comment: As the linked answer indicated, the error was a bug in earlier versions of Xcode, and they are now fixed. The above code compiles. The source of the ambiguity was the infinite loop. (It now compiles the infinite loop and then crashes at runtime if you leave it in.)

Comment: Do you have a piece of sample code that demonstrates this issue with the latest Xcode?

Comment: I compile this code on the most recent version of XCode (6.0.1). I'll update my question with my actual code.

Comment: No; that compiles fine in 6.1, at least as you've given it. I had to throw the usage into a method of a class. I just threw `class X { func bob() { ... } }` around it.

Comment: There is no XCode 6.1, is there ? The latest version is 6.0.1 ?

Comment: Okay, just tested in playground... Seems to work there

Comment: Oh wow, that's strange... It does not show in my member center. Thanks a lot!