# Disambiguate overriden method written in ObjC used in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, swift3, overriding

Complete code: https://github.com/minbi/ambiguous-swift

Is there a way to disambiguate use of an ObjC method from Swift 3?
I need to make the modification in ObjC so that the usage in Swift is as seamless as possible.

Objective C bridged to Swift

```
@interface A
+ (instancetype)singletonA;
@end
@interface B: A
+ (instancetype)singletonB;
@end
```

Usage in Swift 3.

I don't understand why this would be ambiguous. Doesn't the fact that I call the method from `B` "disambiguate the usage even a little?

```
var b: B! = B.singleton()
```

Error

```
Ambiguous use of 'singleton()'
```

Comment: Show enough code to reproduce your issue. I cannot see any errors with your code shown.

Comment: Hard to say anything just shown `A` and `B`. Update your question when you are ready. Many readers would check updated questions.

Comment: I created a brand-new project, put all your revised code into the project, filled some missing parts by guess, **still no error**. Create a new project which can reproduce your issue and show **WHOLE CODE** of it, if you really want to solve your issue.

Comment: Really? I reproduced with just mainly those lines in a new project. I'll upload to Github. Hang tight. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Added complete, whole code. Xcode 8.2.1

Comment: Seems you just had to update two lines of your code above. `@interface A: NSObject` and `@interface B: A`. Giving them completely different names like `+ (instancetype)sharedAInstance;` and `+ (instancetype)sharedBInstance;`, and you can use it as `var b = B.sharedBInstance()`. Or do you have any other requirements still hiding?

Comment: I was trying to see if there was a way to keep the Swift usage the same and just modify or annotate the ObjC somehow. I know `NS_SWIFT_NAME` is available to change the method name, but I wanted to know if there was a similar way to disambiguate the usage.

Comment: Why don't you give the same name `+ (instancetype)singleton` for both `A` and `B`?

Comment: I hesitate to do that because it would be a breaking change for the ObjC side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a known bug. Swift does not handle overriding methods or properties well.

["Ambiguous use of 'propertyName'" error given overridden property with didSet observer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087011/ambiguous-use-of-propertyname-error-given-overridden-property-with-didset-ob?noredirect=1&lq=1)